# Apache mod_rewrite doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want use mod_rewrite but seems that is not working, I activated it and I setup in my .htaccess but nothing seems to work.
I want to NOT display index.php in my URL : 
instead of

```
localhost/index.php/admin/login
```

I want to display

```
localhost/admin/login
```

I am under Ubuntu
Here is what my phpinfo() says :

[image]

This is my .htaccess :

```
# Make sure directory listing is disabled
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteBase /virtualpost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/virtualpost]

#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!localhost).)*$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]

# Remove index.php from URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With}    !^XMLHttpRequest$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}              ^[^/]*/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$            $1 [R=301,NS,L]

# Keep people out of codeigniter directory and Git/Mercurial data
RedirectMatch 403 ^/(system\/virtualpost\/cache|system\/codeigniter|\.git|\.hg).*$

# Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetEnv MYSQL_DB_HOST localhost
    SetEnv MYSQL_USER root
    SetEnv MYSQL_PASSWORD spaces
    SetEnv MYSQL_DB_NAME clevvermail
    <Directory ...>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /admin/login was not found on this server.

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is really enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: hmmm, no, I didn'T get 500 error. So how should I activate .htaccess ?

Comment: I am not sure because Apache installation can vary a lot across different systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I had to config the apache2.conf file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf and change`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None   <<-- Rewriting desactivated
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All  <<--Activate rewriting
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```